# Where should I initialize a listener?

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

For the moment I initialize a listener (extending `PhoneStateListener`) from an activity (in its `onCreate()` method).

```
private static boolean listening = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...

    if (!listening) {
        MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener(getApplicationContext());
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

        listening = true;
    }
```

However, I realized I should initialize that listener when the device is rebooted as well, so I should also start it from the boot completed `BroadcastReceiver`.

How do I then avoid having two instances of that listener running?
(Also I wondered, if the activity is not running (app in background? switched activity?), will my listener always function?)

Comment: I did not understand the requirement. But cant you check if the listener is not null? if it is null initialize it else let it be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Class ListenerUtil,add a static variable for your listener in it,then you can access the static variable in both activity and BroadcastReceiver.Finally,if your activity is not destroied your listener will always work.